# Is every symmetric monoidal combinatorial model category symmetric monoidally Quillen equivalent to a simplicial such?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, symmetric-monoidal-categories

Is every symmetric monoidal combinatorial model category symmetric monoidally Quillen equivalent (by a zig-zag of symmetric monoidal Quillen equivalences) 
to a symmetric monoidal combinatorial simplicial model category?

Do we have a symmetric monoidal version of Dugger's theorem?

Is this true and if yes, where do I find a reference for that?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is proved in https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01475 by Thomas Nikolaus and Steffen Sagave.

If you need a specific monoidal left Quillen equivalence, you can upgrade Dugger's result to the symmetric monoidal setting. One proceeds as in Dugger's proof. Start with the Reedy model structure on simplicial objects. Equip it with the degreewise monoidal product, which turns it into a monoidal model category (see, e.g., Ghazel-Kadhi). Now perform a left Bousfield localization with respect to hocolim-equivalences, as in Dugger's proof. The resulting model category is a monoidal because monoidal products preserve filtered colimits (see, e.g., Gorchinskiy-Guletskii).  A symmetric monoidal Quillen equivalence connects it to the original category, like in Dugger's proof.

Comment: Not quite: That paper proves that any symmetric monoidal left adjoint functor between presentably symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories is represented by a strong symmetric monoidal left Quillen functor between _simplicial_, combinatorial and left proper symmetric monoidal model categories (as stated in the abstract). As they recall in the introduction, the presentable $\infty$-category associated to a symmetric monoidal combinatorial model category is canonically endowed with a symmetric monoidal structure, to which we can associate a simplicial model category. But then?

Comment: So using the paper of Nikolaus and Sagave one can do the following: Starting with a  symmetric monoidal combinatorial model category $\mathcal{M} $ one gets an underlying presentably symmetric monoidal ∞-category $\mathcal{M}_\infty $. By the main theorem of their paper $\mathcal{M}_\infty $ is modeled as a symmetric monoidal ∞-category by a symmetric monoidal combinatorial simplicial model category $\mathcal{N}$, i.e. there is an equivalence $\mathcal{M}_\infty \simeq  \mathcal{N}_\infty$ of  symmetric monoidal ∞-categories.

Comment: But how can one deduce then that $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are linked by a  zig-zag of symmetric monoidal Quillen equivalences?

Comment: I guess that is precisely what is missing and it turns out to require a theorem _à la_ Dugger as you asked in the OP.

Comment: @AndreaGagna: I added an explicit construction.

Comment: @HadrianHeine: I added an explicit construction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats's great. And it should be easy to show that the canonical symmetric monoidal functor from simplicial sets to simplicial objects in the symmetric monoidal combinatorial model category we start with will preserve weak equivalences so that we get a simplicial symmetric monoidal model structure.

Comment: What is your argument that the resulting Bousfield-localization with respect to hocolim equivalences is monoidal using that monoidal products preserve filtered colimits?

Comment: @HadrianHeine: By the criterion of Gorchinskiy-Guletskii, in order to show that some left Bousfield localization L_S(C) is a monoidal model category it is necessary and sufficient that the derived monoidal product (in C) of any object in C and any morphism in S is a weak equivalence in L_S(C).  In the case under consideration weak equivalences are hocolim-equivalences, so the above condition follows immediately from the fact that the left derived functor of X⊗− preserves filtered homotopy colimits.

Comment: In which paper of Gorchinskiy-Guletskii do I find the criterion that it is enough to check that the derived monoidal product of any object in C and any morphism in S is a weak equivalence in L_S(C)? To apply this criterion do we need to assume that the domains and codomains of the generating cofibrations of C are cofibrant?

Comment: @HadrianHeine: This is Lemma 28 in arXiv:0907.0730v4.  If you use derived monoidal products, there is no need to make any assumptions.  For nonderived monoidal products all objects involved must be (made) cofibrant (by applying the cofibrant replacement functor, which amounts to deriving the monoidal product).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Before the authors state lemma 28, they assume that the domains and codomains of the generating cofibrations of the model category are cofibrant, in which the left Bousfield localization takes place.If the domains and codomains of the generating cofibrations of a model category are cofibrant, can we choose the generating cofibrations of the induced Reedy-model category such that their domains and codomains are cofibrant, too?

Comment: @HadrianHeine: The explicit expression for generating cofibrations of the Reedy model structure guarantees this to be true.  However, the only reason this assumption is made in Lemma 28 is to avoid cofibrantly replacing X.  If you replace X by Q(X) in the statement, there is no need to assume this.